# Admin user does not have access to records on lightning

Tags: lightning, permissions, contact, record-access-level

I'm having trouble accessing some activities objects from the account object page. I can access some activities but not others. The permissions error became a problem for our organisation yesterday.

I am an admin and have checked my user permissions and permission sets as well as the permission checks in this article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_insufficient_privileges_object.htm&type=5 and all suggest I should have access.

[image: Admin user not granted permission for contact]

[image: Admin granted access to similar record]

To further confuse things some records that had this problem unexpectedly stopped producing the error and there is no issue accessing the records in salesforce classic. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't it but make sure your profile has "modify all" permission for that record

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have "modify all data" checked and I just added a permission set with edit access to all fields of the task object. Should these have the same effect?

Comment: The "modify all data" object is a bit more universal. The "modify all" on the object level does the same thing but for that object specifically. Giving access to all fields does not give access to all records. I would do a bit of research into Sharing Rules in Salesforce as it will help clarify these for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was caused by trying to access archived activities. Salesforce archives activities after one year. I contacted salesforce support and they increased the length of time before they archive activities in my org which solved the problem.